# mySQL query with DISTINCT (and GROUP BY gives me an error)

Tags: mysql, distinct

I'm trying to get this query below to NOT return duplicate VALUES. What happens is, all rows are 'unique' but they have duplicate values. I tried using GROUP BY adding the max() clause all the values but it keeps giving me an error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
users.firstname,
users.lastname,
users.id,
users.displayname,
mixes.artist,
mixes.title,
mixes.id,
multitracks.artist,
multitracks.id,
multitracks.title
FROM users, mixes, multitracks
WHERE users.displayname = 'KarriGrl'
AND (mixes.userId = users.id OR multitracks.userId = users.id);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that you really want distinct on all those columns.  Please show us some sample data along with the expected output.

Comment: cleaned up the query a little bit. here's a screenshot of the results for example:

Comment: Why the cross join? Just so you're aware, the distinction applies to all columns returned within your select

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra result set will include NULL as a distinct value

Comment: Here's my current output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7fvke9vm3kvky1/mysql.png?dl=1 Note that if you look at the id columns next to title (mixes.id, and multitracks.id respectively), there are repeated valued there. Basically, I don't want to repeat the entire row if an ID has already been shown.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use like this

```
WHERE (users.id IS NULL OR  users.displayname = 'Test123')
```

Comment: sorry, I had that users.id = null there that was incorrect. Just fixed it to just include one condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend ditching the old-school comma  syntax for the join operation, and replace it with `JOIN` keyword. Also consider moving the join predicates from the `WHERE` clause to an `ON` clause.

The query appears to be producing a semi-Cartesian product... every matched row from `mixes` repeated for every matched row from `multitracks`.

Without sample data, and an example of expected output, we're just guessing at the specification.

My guess is that we want to return all of the `mixes` related to specific user, plus all of the `multitracks` related to that same user.

My suggestion is two separate SELECT statements, with the results combined with `UNION` or `UNION ALL` set operator.  I'd also include a discriminator column, which indicates which `SELECT` returned each row.

Something like this:

```
(
  SELECT umx.firstname
       , umx.lastname
       , umx.id
       , umx.displayname
       , 'mixes'           AS `src`
       , mx.artist
       , mx.title
       , mx.id
    FROM users umx
    JOIN mixes mx
      ON mx.userId = umx.id
   WHERE umx.displayname = 'KarriGrl'
   ORDER
      BY mx.artist
       , mx.title
       , mx.id
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT umt.firstname
       , umt.lastname
       , umt.id
       , umt.displayname
       , 'multitracks'     AS `src`
       , mt.artist
       , mt.title
       , mt.id
    FROM users umt
    JOIN multitracks mt
      ON mt.userId = umt.id
   WHERE umt.displayname = 'KarriGrl'
   ORDER
      BY mt.artist
       , mt.title
       , mt.id
)
```

If we need to remove "duplicate" rows from the set, we could replace `UNION ALL` with `UNION`.

Again, this is based on a *guess* at the actual specification.

Comment: this is great, and yes, your assumption is correct. I'd like to return all of the mixes related to specific user, plus all of the multitracks related to that same user without repeating the values in different Mixes <> MTs orders. I will try this one tonight and let you know how it goes. Thanks again for your help btw!

Comment: If we want the entire set sorted in a particular order, we can add an ORDER BY following that last close paren, e.g.  `ORDER BY title ASC, src DESC, artist DESC`.  (The `ORDER BY` clause inside the parens applies to just the set returned by that SELECT. The `UNION ALL` operator just concatenates the set (there's no guarantee of the order of the result from that, but what we observe is that we get the first set, followed by the second set.) If we replace `UNION ALL` with `UNION`, we get a different order, because that forces a "Using filesort" on the concat'd set, to find/remove duplicates/)